# Cauchy Principal Value Integral calculation

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How can i resolve this integral in Cauchy principal value?
$$\int_{-\infty}^ \infty \! \frac{x+\sin x}{x(x^2+4j-4)^2} \ \mathrm{d}x  $$
Then
 $$\int_{-\infty}^ \infty \! \frac{1}{(x^2+4j-4)^2} \ \mathrm{d}x + \frac {1}{2j} \int_{-\infty}^ \infty \! \frac{e^{jz}-e^{-jz}}{x(x^2+4j-4)^2} \ \mathrm{d}x  $$
I usually resolve them with Jordan's lemmas, easily applicable to the second one, but for the first one?

Comment: does "sen"="$\sin$" and "$j:=\sqrt{-1}$"??

Comment: Yes. Perhaps it's better to write "sin x" instead of "sen x" and "i" instead of "j"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\newcommand{\b}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\ub}{\underbrace}
\newcommand{\t}{\text}
\newcommand{\s}{\sqrt}
I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x+\sin x}{x(x^2+4i-4)^2}{\rm d}x=\ub{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x^2+4i-4)^2}{\rm d}x}_{I_1}+\ub{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x(x^2+4i-4)^2}{\rm d}x}_{I_2}\\
\t{Now:}
\\I_1=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{({x-2\s{1-i}})^2(x+2\sqrt{1-i})^2}{\rm d}x\\
\t{Now taking a disc in positive imaginary argand plane and integrating$\\$ around the contour along with taking residue at the root in the upper plane:}\\
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{({x-2\s{1-i}})^2(x+2\sqrt{1-i})^2}{\rm d}x=2\pi i\b{\frac1{64}i\s{1-i}}=-\frac{\pi}{32}\s{1-i}$$